# Joomla 1.5 2 categories, 2 layouts

Tags: templates, joomla, overriding, joomla1.5, joomla-template

I have two categories that need their own layout. Right now it looks like both categories are using `template/html/com_content/category/blog.php`, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to switch this to a different layout from the menu item layout selection.

Joomla 1.5
Stuff I have read:

- http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides
- http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

No matter where I place extra files within `...my-template/html/com_content/category` or `...my-template/html/com_content/category/views/[category]/[tmpl]/`, no new layouts show up from the layout selection dialog. System debug doesn't seem to print out any useful templating info either.

WHAT DO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put layout overrides it the html folder of your template not in the core folders. Look at beez5 for examples of layout over ride and also for an alternative layout which is used in com_contact.

Comment: sorry, the files I'm placing are indeed already in template folders.

Comment: You're in 1.5 so it's basically all or nothing in a given template. Either you use the core layout always or you use the template override always. THe only option is to make a copy of the template and use a different override for that and only use that template when you want to have that specific category. 2.5 -3 is much more flexible on this.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for explaining! I was indeed confused about the lack of template flexibility.